# Hide Calendar Button on DatePicker?

Tags: javafx, datepicker

Is there a simple way to hide the calendar button on the DatePicker Node in JavaFX?  Some of our dates are not editable, and the calendar button is just adding to the width of the field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following css to remove the calendar button

```
.date-picker > .arrow-button {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}

.date-picker > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}
```

**Edit** - To get back the right border :

```
.date-picker > .date-picker-display-node {
    -fx-background-insets: 1 1 1 1;
}
```

---

**Edit** - To apply the above style to only few datepickers

Declare a DatePicker and add a styleclass to it.

```
DatePicker nonEditableDatePicker = new DatePicker();
nonEditableDatePicker.getStyleClass().add("non-editable-datepicker");
```

Use this styleclass to add styles :

```
.non-editable-datepicker > .arrow-button {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}

.non-editable-datepicker > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}

.non-editable-datepicker > .date-picker-display-node {
    -fx-background-insets: 1 1 1 1;
}
```

Comment: So this definitely removes the button, however it also removes the right border of the field.

`.date-picker > .arrow-button {
    -fx-padding: px;
}

.date-picker > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}`

This is slightly better, but still not perfect

Comment: How would you suggest selectively applying this style to specific DatePickers, since I obviously would not want it to apply to DatePickers that should be editable.